# Call to undefined function error

Tags: php, mysql, function

I am getting a `call to undefined function` error, when I have defined a function. Here is the code:

```
foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM 'members' WHERE username = '$user'") as $row) {
    echo "Rank: ".get_rank_tag($user)."<br>";
}
```

**Here is the class for the `get_rank_tag()` function**

```
include('password.php');

class User extends Password {
  private $_db;

  function __construct($db) {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_db = $db;
  }

  public function get_rank_tag($user){   
     try {
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT rank FROM members WHERE username = $user ');
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        if($row['rank']==0){return "<span class='label label-default'>Default</span>";}
        elseif($row['rank']==1){return "<span class='label label-success'>VIP</span>";}
        elseif($row['rank']==2){return "<span class='label label-success'>MVP</span>";}
        elseif($row['rank']==3){return "<span class='label label-success'>Elite</span>";}
        elseif($row['rank']==4){return "<span class='label label-success'>Master</span>";}
        elseif($row['rank']==5){return "<span class='label label-success'>Champion</span>";}
        elseif($row['rank']==6){return "<span class='label label-primary'>JM</span>";}
        elseif($row['rank']==7){return "<span class='label label-primary'>Trusted</span>";}
        elseif($row['rank']==8){return "<span class='label label-info'>GM</span>";}
        elseif($row['rank']==9){return "<span class='label label-info'>GM+</span>";}
        elseif($row['rank']==10){return "<span class='label label-warning'>Admin</span>";}
        elseif($row['rank']==11){return "<span class='label label-danger'>Owner</span>";}
     } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '';
     }
  }

}
```

I am a bit of a beginner to PHP, so please bear with me.

Comment: Where is the call to the undefined function occurring?

Comment: ...and what is the name of the undefined function? Always show full error messages!

Comment: @Chitowns24 when I say`".get_rank_tag($user)."`

Comment: @JonathonReinhart **Fatal Error**: Call to undefined function get_rank_tag() in **/Applications/AMPPS/www/profiles.php** on line **20**

Comment: I believe you are using a framework, could you tell us what framework you are using?

Comment: no no no no no.. you are getting started with wrong thing, you are new to PHP and Programming also (because you also lacks some basics of OOP too) you need to get started with simple and understandable tasks/codes

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have an instance of the `User` class? Be sure you have instantiated the class as PHP won't be able to identify your function.

Comment: I used `include 'classes/user.php';`

Comment: You only "included" the `User` class. You need to have `$user_class = new User($db);` to be able to use the function you needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new instance of the class before you can start calling functions within it, otherwise it has no idea where to look for the functions

```
$newUser = new User($db);
$dataHold = $newUser->get_rank_tag($user);
```

Then you can use `$dataHold` in place where you are echo'ing the rank.

Comment: Now I get this error:



**Fatal error:** Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in **/Applications/AMPPS/www/classes/user.php** on line **71**

Comment: Yeah you need to add a database to this call. So the class knows what database you are using. What framework are you in?

Comment: Now the place that I have `'.$newUser->get_rank_tag($user).'` echos nothing. Also no frameworks, well bootstrap I guess...

Comment: Could you be getting a PDO exception? When you got one you echo '' which is what you said is being echo'ed?

Comment: yup. `exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '$user' in 'where clause'' in /Applications/AMPPS/www/classes/user.php:72 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/AMPPS/www/classes/user.php(72): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /Applications/AMPPS/www/profiles.php(21): User->get_rank_tag('ryr11') #2 {main}`
any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you defining $user before running your Query?

Comment: yeah. with `$user = $_GET['user'];`

Comment: use '$user' in your get_rank_tag code. right now it just says $user